# Unity, WebClient does not work in build for Android when I would like to read a text from file.txt which is on a server

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, webclient

Good evening. I would like to read a text from a txt-file which is on a server (like https://example-files.online-convert.com/document/txt/example.txt). In Editor it works correctly, but in a build for Android it throws an exception. I have also put "required" instead of "auto" in player settings.

I have two scripts, the script ShowingTheTextFromASevrer is hung on the Main Camera. Also there is a Text (TextMeshProUGUI) on the screen. In a build I see "An exception occured during a WebClient request" on the screen.

How to fix it?

```
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;

public abstract class GettingTextFromAServer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string GetTheTextFromAServer(string url)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        Stream stream = client.OpenRead(url);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        return reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

```
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class ShowingTheTextFromASevrer : GettingTextFromAServer
{
    [SerializeField] private TextMeshProUGUI TextOnTheScreen;

    private void Start()
    {
        TextOnTheScreen.text = "";
        string TextFromTheServer;
        try
        {
            TextFromTheServer = GetTheTextFromAServer("https://example-files.online-convert.com/document/txt/example.txt");
            Debug.Log(TextFromTheServer);
            TextOnTheScreen.text += TextFromTheServer;
        }
        catch (System.Exception AnyException)
        {
            TextOnTheScreen.text += AnyException.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

UPD: Maybe, I should modify the mainfest. I have found it, it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.unity3d.player"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <application>
        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity"
                  android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Where should I put

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

or analogical?

UPD-2:
I have solved that.

1. In the manifest

```
    <permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

should be put above the "application" tag.
2) The app should be signed with keycode (like we do before the publication to Play Market) to work.

Comment: Being mobile, does the Android app need certain _permission declarations_ (such as Network I/O) that are read and possibly granted by the user whilst the app is installed?

Comment: That is intersting. I have updated the question